# Compare last two elasticsearch inputs and show smaller

Tags: elasticsearch

I have nested query where I want to compare last two inputs and display smaller one.

For example:

```
"price_history":[
{"id":0,
 "price":16.99,
 "date":"2021-02-07"
},
 "id":1,
 "price":20.99,
 "date":"2021-02-08"
},
{"id":2,
 "price":16.99,
 "date":"2021-02-09"
}
]
```

So I want only id 1 and 2 to be compared and only id 2 to be shown.

I am looking for help to build such a query and am open to any other data model suggestions.

Comment: please remember to mark the answer as correct if it was useful for your problem or let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to compare the last 2 prices and display the lowest. That information can be calculated on index time so it should be done there instead of re-calculating on each query.

I will show you how to do it on index time assuming you have no control on the software is ingesting the data using a [Pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html) that will process your data before putting it in elasticsearch.

We are going to create a new field called best_price that store this price so you can then make queries against this field instead of calculate it on each query.

**Ingesting data**

```
POST test_uzer/_doc
{
  "price_history": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "price": 16.99,
      "date": "2021-02-07"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 20.99,
      "date": "2021-02-08"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 16.99,
      "date": "2021-02-09"
    }
  ]
}

POST test_uzer/_doc
{
  "price_history": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "price": 1.99,
      "date": "2021-02-07"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 15.99,
      "date": "2021-02-08"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 16.99,
      "date": "2021-02-09"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Creating the ingest pipeline**

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/best_price
{
  "description": "return the best price between the 2 last",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "def prices = ctx.price_history; def length = prices.length; ctx.best_price = prices[length - 1].price > prices[length - 2].price ? prices[length - 2].price : prices[length - 1].price"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Reindexing the data to have the new field**

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "test_uzer"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "test_uzer_new",
    "pipeline": "best_price"
  }
}
```

**Add the ingest pipeline as default to apply to all the new documents**

```
PUT test_uzer_new/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "default_pipeline": "best_price"
  }
}
```

**Ingest document to test**

```
POST test_uzer_new/_doc
{
  "price_history": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "price": 2,
      "date": "2021-02-07"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 3,
      "date": "2021-02-08"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 1,
      "date": "2021-02-09"
    }
  ]
}
```

**best_price should be 1**

`POST test_uzer_new/_search`

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_uzer_new",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "a8oz-ncBRP0FeAG5geN1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "best_price" : 16.99,
          "price_history" : [
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-07",
              "price" : 16.99,
              "id" : 0
            },
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-08",
              "price" : 20.99,
              "id" : 1
            },
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-09",
              "price" : 16.99,
              "id" : 2
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_uzer_new",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bMpE-ncBRP0FeAG54ONR",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "best_price" : 15.99,
          "price_history" : [
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-07",
              "price" : 1.99,
              "id" : 0
            },
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-08",
              "price" : 15.99,
              "id" : 1
            },
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-09",
              "price" : 16.99,
              "id" : 2
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_uzer_new",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bspJ-ncBRP0FeAG59uOi",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "best_price" : 1,
          "price_history" : [
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-07",
              "price" : 2,
              "id" : 0
            },
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-08",
              "price" : 3,
              "id" : 1
            },
            {
              "date" : "2021-02-09",
              "price" : 1,
              "id" : 2
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Works!

Of course there are many ways to achieve what you want, but the point is index and calculate as much data as you can **before** querying. This will make your searches faster.

Comment: Yes that is working thank you. My only concern is that lowest price will be calculated even if I don't need it. Isn't that very inefficient approach?

Comment: I dont think so. It is a light operation and made only once per document vs "n" times (one per query) . Please remember to mark the answer as correct. Thanks